# Edit DataGridViewCell on readonly object property

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I've bound a DataGridView to a `BindingList<MyObj>` which has the Value property readonly (protected).

So there I have a method to change its value (`MyObj.SetValue(string newValue)`).

The standard behavior of DataGridView is also to lock the cell editing, but there's no way to "simulate" an editing and then pass the correct method to update the value?

I tried to set the `column.ReadOnly = false`, but it throws an exception. It doesn't fire the `CellBeginEdit` event, so will I have to create another textbox in front of it to do this?

Comment: Add a Column to the DataGridView not bound to any of the properties of your class and call the public method when the value of the Cells of this Column changes. It's not exactly clear why you have a read-only property when you actually want to change its value (since you bind it to a DGV, that is). Could you do what the public method is doing in the property setter instead? Or use the validation features to validate/reject an *improper* value (maybe using a public or non-public method of your class object, why not)

Comment: What Exception do you get exactly when you change the `column.ReadOnly` property to `false`?

Answer (score 0):

As per MSDN, it would seem the only exception will be:

> Exceptions
>   InvalidOperationException
>   There is no owning row when setting this property.
>
> -or-
>
> The owning row is shared when setting this property.

So, check if the is actually an `OwningRow`, or if that row happens to be shared.

Also, the `Remark section` says:

> The ReadOnly property indicates whether the data displayed by the cell can be edited. > > You can set ReadOnly for individual cells, or you can make an entire row or column of > > cells read-only by setting the DataGridViewRow.ReadOnly or DataGridViewColumn.ReadOnly > > properties. By default, if a cell's parent row or column is set to read-only, the child > cells will adopt the same value. You can override this default behavior by setting > > > > ReadOnly for individual cells.
>
> You can navigate to a read-only cell, and you can set a read-only cell to be the current > cell.
>
> ReadOnly only affects whether a cell is editable; it does not affect whether the user > > can delete rows.

Sounds like it's all there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried before to set the cells to ReadOnly = false, but I couldn't, because the DataGridView was bound to an object which has an property that is ReadOnly, so I think by default it may take the object settings. 
So, then I did create another object with other properties which I update later on a Save() void...